# Azure Load Balance Virtual Machines in a Subnetwork

Tags: networking, mysql, load-balancing, azure, mysql-replication

If I have 2 subnetworks, 10.0.0.0 for my processes and 11.0.0.0 for databases, how can I load balance the databases internally within the subnetwork such that any of the processes in 10.0.0.0 network can access any of the database instances via single internal IP like 11.0.0.4?

So 11.0.0.4 would load balance lets say 3 virtual machines at 11.0.0.5, 11.0.0.6 and 11.0.0.7.

The IP addresses are given purely to demonstrate the point and I understand that they may look different when actually done.

Or is a better solution to have a completely separate virtual network for the database servers and connect both virtual networks together. If so what configuration would you recommend for this?

I want to avoid going out to the Internet only to come back in again to access the database from the processes. Speed is of essence and all machines are in the same region.

All machines are running Ubuntu 15.10 if that's of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subnets are perfect the way they are.  No change needed there.  What you need is an **internal load balancer** sitting in from your database servers.

If you are using Azure Resource Manager, [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-arm-powershell/) are the steps to set this up?

If you are using the older/classic networks and virtual machines, then [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-getstarted/) are the steps to configure in that environment.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying it now, will accept once I've verified it all works